# Android close previous Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I want to start the main activity from Broadcastresiver twice but close the previous one?

```
pop.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
```

But it doesn't work?

Comment: Why do you want to start the same activity twice? Do you mean, you are calling MainActivity Intent from MainActivity?

Comment: no there is an action created in broadcastreciver and i want to excuted in mainActivity and there is no way except start the activity but i want to remove previous MainActivity old one are you understand me

Comment: you want to remove mainActivity from your backstack ? Is your app contains multiple activity.

Comment: show some of your code, where are you calling the activity Your flags should handle that the activity that called the new activity wont have onBack() option to return to the previous activity. So something must go wrong in your code.

Comment: Thanks alot to all the problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

for finishing activity you can call finishaffinity() or finish()

Comment: Just calling `this.finish();` save my day, after calling `startActivity(intent);`, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

First Read Android Developers for more information

[Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

and then for close or finish activity you need to use

```
this.finish();
or
this.finishaffinity();
```

hope it help.